# Outer product form of the SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Here is a proof of the outer product form of the SVD (from a textbook):[image]

I am unfamiliar with multiplying partitioned matrices. Can anyone please point me towards some standard theorems or lemmas about partitioned matrices that are being used in this proof?

Comment: For example, if $A$ has the block structure $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} B_1 \\ B_2 \end{bmatrix}$, then $AB = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} B_1 + A_{12} B_2 \\ A_{21} B_1 + A_{22} B_2 \end{bmatrix}$ (assuming that the blocks of $A$ and $B$ are of compatible sizes). It's the same formula you would have if the blocks of $A_{ij}$ and $B_j$ were scalars rather than matrices.

Comment: The block multiplication in this instance is a bit more complicated than your example, can you please clarify a little?

Comment: @littleO's example seems clear enough; if everything is conformably partitioned, just take two components at a time and multiply them as in his comment.